# Default export of subroutine (constant) does not work; why?

Tags: perl, module

I write some code that creates constants on the fly in a module, and those constants should be exported.
However that did not work:

It seems the default `@EXPORT` is just being ignored, because using an explicit qualifier works.

I made a kind of minimal example, so don't ask what the sense of the code is:

```perl
% cat Bad.pm
package Bad;

require 5.018_000;
use warnings;
use strict;

use constant LIST => [qw(ABC DEF)];

our (@EXPORT, @EXPORT_OK, $VERSION);
BEGIN {
    require Exporter;
    our $VERSION = 1.00; # for version checking
    @EXPORT = @EXPORT_OK = @{(LIST)};
}

BEGIN {
    sub ABC () { 0; }
    sub DEF () { 1; }
}

ABC; # no error!

1;
% cat badtest.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Bad;

exit Bad::DEF; # no error
exit ABC; # error!
```

So what's wrong with the `@EXPORT`?

The error message is:

```text
Bareword "ABC" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at badtest.pl line 8.
Execution of badtest.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
 at badtest.pl line 8.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import the `import` sub from [Exporter](http://p3rl.org/Exporter) to your module. It's usually done by

```
use Exporter qw{ import };
```

or, if you insist on `require` instead of `use`:

```
require Exporter;
Exporter->import('import');
```

or

```
require Exporter;
*import = *Exporter::import{CODE};
```

Comment: Re "*if you insist on require instead of use:*", It's a BEGIN block. There's no reason to insist on it. `use Exporter qw{ import };` right before the block is the same as using `require`+`import` in the block.

Comment: Can you explain .please: I thought the symbols from `@EXPORT` are imported by default when you do not say differently. The manual of `Exporter` explains: "*"use YourModule;":
This imports all the symbols from YourModule's @EXPORT into the namespace of the "use" statement.*"

Comment: @U. Windl Yeah, but you didn't make it so Exporter is used. For that, you need `use Exporter qw( import );` (or the old way that involves inheritance)

Comment: I got it: Either use `require Exporter; @ISA = qw(Exporter);` or `use Exporter qw(import);`. Somehow I was assuming the magic happens when `use`ing the module.

Comment: @U. Windl It should explort `import` by default, but backwards compatibility...